# Why does 'static' keyword allow the function to return correct reference?

Tags: c++, reference, static

Why doesn't the first code work (runtime error) while the second works?
Code 1:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Both these code snippets have been taken from geeksforgeeks (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/ ).

Comment: I can't still find the answer. I have read the complete post.

Comment: Your first version is returning a reference to a variable that is destroyed at the end of the function. After the function returns, the reference refers to a destroyed object and accessing it is Undefined Behaviour. In the second version `static` extends the lifetime of the local variable to be the duration of the program, thus the reference you return stays valid.

Comment: @KrittikaChhabra The memory for the variable in your 1st version is allocated at the stack, while it's not with the second version. The stack memory will be cleared after the function returns, thus accessing that reference is _undefined behavior_ in this case..

Comment: Ok. That helped. Thanks :)

Comment: The life-time of `int x;` ends with its scope (i.e. at `}`). So, accessing it outside of function is illegal. The `static int x;` starts to live (at latest) at 1st access until end of process. Hence, you may access it outside function without problems. But, please, be aware that it is only one and the same `static int x` for every call of function `fun()`.